# asp.net Garbage Collection Notifications

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection

Has anyone implement this new feature in .net 3.5 SP1 in an asp.net environment?  The only thing I can find the web is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp_net_gc_notifications2.aspx), which is not an actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

in 3.5sp1, we have introduced 2 new APIs that tells you when a new Gen2 notification is approaching
Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647167.aspx for more details.

Comment: Hi mfawzymkh,

Do you know of any real world asp.net implementation that take advantage of these 2 new API?  Ideally, I'll like to notify of load balancer to not talk the server that is about to perform a full GC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess one problem with notifying the Load Balancer is that once the GC is triggered, the CLR halts all threads in order to GC.

So even if your code could receive a notification, it is not going to be able to react to it.

Comment: you get the notification before the GC happens